# adb.exe not working in Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, android

I need help in getting `adb.exe` to work.

OS is Windows 7 SP1, with Comodo internet security suite.

On executing `adb start-server`, I see `adb.exe` in my process list.
And I did `netstat` before starting to see port `5037` was not used by any process.

After starting, I see `adb.exe` with port `5037`, but no further communications with `adb.exe` was possible. e.g. `adb devices` would always return `ADB server didn't ACK` etc.

Even after exiting Comodo, thise symptom remains.

I rebooted Windows in safe mode with networking and was able to connect adb to an emulator in the AVD manager.

I tried ADB on a friend's machine which ran Windows 7 without the SP1, and ADB works.
Now, is there a way to get ADB working properly in Windows 7 with SP1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Exiting Comodo does not stop its firewall.  You need to add an exception through Comodo's firewall.

Comment: I had added adb.exe as trusted application and allow all incoming and outgoing traffic in Comodo before exiting it. No luck.

Comment: My gut says Comodo is the problem.  Their Internet Security Suite is free right?  So what's stopping you from uninstalling it to make sure that's not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Comodo is most likely the problem. I have come across numerous instances where removing the Comodo firewall solves this problem.